# need to remove the the number of review tag

Tags: magento2, product, review, remove

I just want to remove the "3 Reviews" text from my custom module.
for that, I have created a file *view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml file. Please check SS

[image]
My module name is : Remove_Text

```
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="reviews.tab" />
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.review">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Remove_Text::review.phtml</argument>
            </action>
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="custom.review.popup" template="Remove_Text::popup.phtml">
                <block class="Magento\Review\Block\Form" name="custom.product.review.form" as="custom.review_form" template="Remove_Text::form.phtml"/>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 0):

For that, you need to override this file in the custom module and remove class "action view".

magento/module-review/view/frontend/templates/helper/summary.phtml.

Please check the SS.

[image]